# Is there a more readable or more idiomatic way of expressing this query with slick?

Tags: slick, slick-3.0

I'm trying to use slick 3.1.1 to execute the equivalent of the following SQL query:

```
SELECT 
    r.*
FROM Resource r
INNER JOIN User u ON u.id = r.owner_id
INNER JOIN UserCredentials uc ON uc.user_id = u.id 
WHERE r.id = <resource id>
```

I've expressed the query like this:

```
(for ( ((resource,_),_) <- resources
                              join users on (_.userId === _.id)
                              join userCredentials on (_._2.id === _.userId))
  yield resource).filter(_.id === resourceId).result.headOption
```

It feels unwieldly and hard to read.  Is there a cleaner way of writing this query with slick?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For comprehension to the rescue. Inner and cross joins can be expressed as "monadic joins". The following is using inner joins:

```
val query = for {
  r  <- resources if r.id === resourceId
  u  <- users if u.id === r.ownerId
  uc <- userCredentials if uc.userId === u.id
} yield r
```

Check out [slick docs](http://slick.lightbend.com/doc/3.1.1/queries.html) for more examples.

Answer (score 0):

I personally prefer method-style, using partial functions to show row names:

```scala
resources.filter(_.id === resourceId).join(users).on {
  case (resource, user) => resource.userId === user.id
}.join(userCredentials).on {
  case ((_, user), userCredentials) => user.id === userCredentials.userId
}.filter {
  case ((resource, _), _) => resource.id === resourceId
}.map {
  case ((resource, _), _) => resource
}.result.headOption
```

You could also filter `resources` as your first step, which makes thing a bit cleaner:

```scala
resources.filter(_.id === resourceId).join(users).on {
  case (resource, user) => resource.userId === user.id
}.join(userCredentials).on {
  case ((_, user), userCredentials) => user.id === userCredentials.userId
}.map {
  case ((resource, _), _) => resource
}.result.headOption
```

I hope that helps!